# Writing an incremental integer supplier

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm trying to get some grasps over the Java 8 functional programming. I tried to write the following `IntSupplier` "functionally" but I keep getting issues.

```
import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

    @Test public void test_nonFunctional() {
        IntSupplier supplier = new IntSupplier() {
            private int nextInt = 0;
            @Override public int getAsInt() {
                return nextInt++;
            }
        };
    }
```

Here are my attempts. The issues are marked as comments in the code.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

public class IntSupplierTest {
    @Test public void test_nonFunctional() {
        IntSupplier supplier = new IntSupplier() {
            private int nextInt = 0;
            @Override public int getAsInt() { return nextInt++; }
        }; // Works but is not functional.
    }

    @Test public void test_naive() {
        int nextInt = 0;
        IntSupplier supplier = () -> nextInt++; // Doesn't compile: requires nextInt to be final.
    }

    @Test public void test_nextIntIsFinal() {
        final int nextInt = 0;
        IntSupplier supplier = () -> nextInt++; // Doesn't compile: nextInt can't be incremented because it's final.
    }

    @Test public void test_useWrapper() {
        final AtomicInteger nextInt = new AtomicInteger(0);
        IntSupplier supplier = () -> nextInt.getAndIncrement(); // It is not the same as my original question as this test uses an extra object.
    }
}
```

If the answer is simply that it cannot be done without using extra objects, please just say so.

Comment: @Mena That doesn't increment over time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of the problem is already non-functional. In functional you can't have different output without an argument. That's the definition. But how to create a sequence of numbers you can see in the java libraries: `java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator`. It's used like this:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i+1).limit(10).foreach(System.out::printLn);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing towards `IntStream::iterate` and reminding the definition (which I had forgotten, shame on me). However, since you remind that definition, I have to add that Java 8 is not a proper functional programming language and it merely uses the functional programming style to simplify some parts of the code.

Comment: oops... your code prints a list of `0`, changing it to `i -> i+1` makes it work.

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like this:

```
IntSupplier supplier = new AtomicInteger(0)::incrementAndGet;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way of working around this problem:

```
int[] nextInt = { 0 }; // optionally mark as final
IntSupplier supplier = () -> nextInt[0]++;
```

but it isn't really any more functional than the "Works but is not functional" solution.